# Como criar os certificados e o provisionamento profile corretamente para uso de Push Notification?

Tags: ios, certificado-digital, ssl, apple-push-notification

Preciso de ajuda para criar um certificado de *provisioning profile* corretamente para **Push Notification**. Pois segui vários tutoriais diferentes, e em todos não tive sucesso. Somente em um momento em que usei o *provisioning profile* de Team que consegui receber as notificações.

Tenho experiência em criar certificados para iOS, pois já tenho 2 aplicativos publicados que usam *push notification*. Porém de algum modo não sei o que está acontecendo.

Coincidência ou não, não estou conseguindo depois das recentes atualizações que acompanharam o lançamento do iOS 8.

Comment: O que exatamente não está dando certo? Você chegou a fazer a requisição de *push* e receber alguma resposta no seu servidor mesmo que negativa?

Answer (score 1):

O lançamento do iOS8 trouxe algumas alterações no modo como os dispositivos recebem notificações. Não sei se o problema que estas a referir é sobre esse aspecto ou mesmo sobre o certificado criado. Por isso vou tentar responder te aos dois.

No primeiro, com o iOS 8, o modo como implementas e processas as notificações é diferente:

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings
                                                                                 settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge)
                                                                                 categories:nil]];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
        else
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
             (UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert)];
        }
```

Sobre os certificados em si, quando pretendes criar uma aplicação com PushNotifications tens que criar um AppID diferente.

1. O bundle identifier não pode ser uma **wildMask**(isto é, usar o * para permitir varias aplicações com diferentes nomes).
2. Ao criar esse AppId tens que pedir autorização para pushNotification(tanto para desenvolvimento como para distribuição). [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este processo obriga te a criar um certificado. Segue a explicação dada na pagina e a partida não deves ter grandes problemas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado da @DaSilva, vou tentar novamente. Tentei varias vezes.... e não tive sucesso. :/

Comment: verificas te se estas a receber o token do dispositivo na app??

Comment: Sim recebo o token normal. Como te falei, meu problema não está no código, está no provisionament profile

Comment: Não é só isso não!